# Identify rows that differs

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct, aggregate

Consider the following table: table1

```
+----+-------+------+--------+
| Id | AppId | Req  | Status |
+----+-------+------+--------+
|  1 | app1  | r1   | m      |
|  2 | app1  | r1   | n      |
|  3 | app1  | r2   | m      |
|  4 | app1  | r3   | m      |
|  5 | app2  | r1   | m      |
|  6 | app2  | r1   | m      |
|  7 | app3  | r1   | m      |
|  8 | app3  | r2   | m      |
|  9 | app3  | r3   | m      |
+----+-------+------+--------+

SELECT 
    T1.AppId,
    COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.Req = r1
GROUP BY T1.AppId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

this would give me the following output:

```
+------+---+
| app1 | 2 |
+------+---+
| app2 | 2 |
+------+---+
```

I would like to have my output as follows so it will add an output only if status differs.
For eg in this case app2    r1      status is 'm'. It does not differ.

```
app1     2
```

Please help me how to write this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with `HAVING COUNT(distinct status) > 1` ?

Like this:

```
SELECT
T1.AppId,
COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.Req = r1
GROUP BY T1.AppId
HAVING COUNT(distinct status) > 1
```

Comment: I copied it from the original query. I modified only the having part.